# C header file with bitmapped fonts

Tags: c, fonts, header, bitmap

I need to do some rudimentary text rendering to a pixel buffer, and I think that having a table indexed by char with the representation of the letters as a binary array would be more than enough... Anybody knows about a free header as such?

Example:

```
char data[256][8][8];
void init()
{
  data['a'] = {
    {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
    {0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0},
    {0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0},
    {0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0},
  };
}
```

I could go on with the rest of the alphabet, but then I wouldn't need to ask... ¡But that gives me an idea! if there's no free header with a bitmapped font readily available, each answer could implement a letter and I could assemble the whole file here ^_^

Comment: I would store 1 bit per pixel instead of 1 byte per pixel... especially since your target font width seems to be exactly 8.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update**: I tried this approach and the characters come out fairly distorted.  Possibly Nimbus is a poor font choice.

Go with the imagemagick approach. You can generate each character with this:

```
convert -resize 7x13\! -font Nimbus-Mono-Regular -pointsize 10 label:A A.xbm
```

A.xbm looks like:

```
#define A_width 7
#define A_height 13
static char A_bits[] = {
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1C, 0x08, 0x00, 0x3C, 0x00, 0x66, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, };
```

Loop through the characters you need and assemble this into a single header file.

Even though Nimbus-Mono-Regular is a monospace font, sometimes the character widths are off by a pixel.  The convert option "-resize 7x13!" forces a 7x13 output size.  Again, this might be a problem specifically with the Nimbus font.

Comment: Sorry to dig up this old post but is there any way I can do the entire font?

Comment: Try something like:
for c in {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9}; do convert -resize 7x13\! -font Nimbus-Mono-Regular -pointsize 10 label:$c xbm:- >> font.xbm; done

Comment: How would I go about using it?

Answer (score 13):

```
unsigned char Bitmap::letters[95][13] = {
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},// space :32
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18},// ! :33
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x36, 0x36, 0x36, 0x36},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x66, 0x66, 0xff, 0x66, 0x66, 0xff, 0x66, 0x66, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x7e, 0xff, 0x1b, 0x1f, 0x7e, 0xf8, 0xd8, 0xff, 0x7e, 0x18},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x0e, 0x1b, 0xdb, 0x6e, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x76, 0xdb, 0xd8, 0x70},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xc6, 0xcf, 0xd8, 0x70, 0x70, 0xd8, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0x6c, 0x38},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x1c, 0x0c, 0x0e},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x18, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x18, 0x30},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x99, 0x5a, 0x3c, 0xff, 0x3c, 0x5a, 0x99, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0xff, 0xff, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x18, 0x1c, 0x1c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x38, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x60, 0x60, 0x30, 0x30, 0x18, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x06, 0x03, 0x03},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x66, 0xc3, 0xe3, 0xf3, 0xdb, 0xcf, 0xc7, 0xc3, 0x66, 0x3c},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x78, 0x38, 0x18},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x03, 0xe7, 0x7e},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0x03, 0x03, 0x07, 0x7e, 0x07, 0x03, 0x03, 0xe7, 0x7e},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0xff, 0xcc, 0x6c, 0x3c, 0x1c, 0x0c},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0x03, 0x03, 0x07, 0xfe, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xff},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc7, 0xfe, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xe7, 0x7e},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0xff},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xe7, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xe7, 0x7e},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x7f, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xe7, 0x7e},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x38, 0x00, 0x00, 0x38, 0x38, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x18, 0x1c, 0x1c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x1c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x0c, 0x18, 0x30, 0x60, 0xc0, 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x06},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x03, 0x06, 0x0c, 0x18, 0x30, 0x60},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x03, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x7e},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 0x60, 0xcf, 0xdb, 0xd3, 0xdd, 0xc3, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xff, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x66, 0x3c, 0x18},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xfe, 0xc7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc7, 0xfe, 0xc7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc7, 0xfe},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xe7, 0x7e},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xfc, 0xce, 0xc7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc7, 0xce, 0xfc},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xfc, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xff},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xfc, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xff},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xcf, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xe7, 0x7e},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xff, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x7e},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7c, 0xee, 0xc6, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06, 0x06},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xc6, 0xcc, 0xd8, 0xf0, 0xe0, 0xf0, 0xd8, 0xcc, 0xc6, 0xc3},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xdb, 0xff, 0xff, 0xe7, 0xc3},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc7, 0xc7, 0xcf, 0xcf, 0xdf, 0xdb, 0xfb, 0xf3, 0xf3, 0xe3, 0xe3},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xe7, 0x7e},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xfe, 0xc7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc7, 0xfe},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x3f, 0x6e, 0xdf, 0xdb, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x66, 0x3c},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xc6, 0xcc, 0xd8, 0xf0, 0xfe, 0xc7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc7, 0xfe},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0x03, 0x03, 0x07, 0x7e, 0xe0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xe7, 0x7e},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0xff},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x3c, 0x3c, 0x66, 0x66, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xe7, 0xff, 0xff, 0xdb, 0xdb, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0x66, 0x66, 0x3c, 0x3c, 0x18, 0x3c, 0x3c, 0x66, 0x66, 0xc3},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x3c, 0x3c, 0x66, 0x66, 0xc3},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0x60, 0x30, 0x7e, 0x0c, 0x06, 0x03, 0x03, 0xff},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x3c},
{0x00, 0x03, 0x03, 0x06, 0x06, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x18, 0x18, 0x30, 0x30, 0x60, 0x60},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x3c},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0x66, 0x3c, 0x18},
{0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x38, 0x30, 0x70},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x7f, 0x03, 0xc3, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xfe, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xfe, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xc3, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc3, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x7f, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xfe, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0xfc, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x33, 0x1e},
{0x7e, 0xc3, 0x03, 0x03, 0x7f, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xfe, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00},
{0x38, 0x6c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc6, 0xcc, 0xf8, 0xf0, 0xd8, 0xcc, 0xc6, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x78},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xdb, 0xdb, 0xdb, 0xdb, 0xdb, 0xdb, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xfc, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7c, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0x7c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xfe, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x7f, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xe0, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xfe, 0x03, 0x03, 0x7e, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x36, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0xfc, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0xc6, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x3c, 0x3c, 0x66, 0x66, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0xe7, 0xff, 0xdb, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0xc3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0x66, 0x3c, 0x18, 0x3c, 0x66, 0xc3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0xc0, 0x60, 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x3c, 0x66, 0x66, 0xc3, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x60, 0x30, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x06, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x0f, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x38, 0xf0, 0x38, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x0f},
{0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18},
{0x00, 0x00, 0xf0, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0x1c, 0x0f, 0x1c, 0x18, 0x18, 0x18, 0xf0},
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x8f, 0xf1, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}  // :126
```

Comment: all ascii charactors, hope it will help you.

Comment: Brilliant, where did you get this from?

Comment: Neat. I notice that lower scanlines come first and left pixels are in more significant bits.

Comment: Silicon Graphics released that bit map here:https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse457/98a/tech/OpenGL/font.c   "Permission to use, copy, modify and distribute this software for any purpose and without fee is hereby granted..."

Comment: I've tried using this bitmap font table and ran into the problem of the text being flipped both vertically and horizontally. So letters were upside down and they were also flipped left to right. What I ended up doing was to transform the output so that rather than going left to right with each character row, I instead traversed right to left. Then when putting each pixel, I went from bit 7 to bit 0 rather than bit 0 to bit 7. The other bitmap font tables I've tried, I did not have this problem including using the dhepper 8x8 font  mentioned by another answer.

Comment: I gave this font a shot, here's a picture of it rendered in game ![default font](https://github.com/briancullinan/planet_quake/blob/master/docs/default_font.png?raw=true) I tried to add some basic rasterizing in C instead of GL. Reversing the characters is a simple subtraction. I wanted something I could embed into code, I think I might go the embedded resources route and use TGA. Something like this might be a better solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864866/c-c-with-gcc-statically-add-resource-files-to-executable-library/4864879#4864879

Answer (score 8):

I ended up using: https://github.com/dhepper/font8x8

A 8x8 monochrome bitmap font.

License: Public Domain

```
void render(char *bitmap) {
    int x,y;
    int set;
    for (x=0; x < 8; x++) {
        for (y=0; y < 8; y++) {
            set = bitmap[x] & 1 << y;
            printf("%c", set ? 'X' : ' ');
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

render(font8x8_basic['A']);
```

Prints:

```
  XX    
 XXXX   
XX  XX  
XX  XX  
XXXXXX  
XX  XX  
XX  XX
```

Comment: I've used this one successfully with a 3.5" TFT LCD display with an Arduino Uno.

Comment: is there a way to use those 8x8 but draw them as 16x16 (doubling the resolution)?

Comment: @navy1978 You can draw a 2x2 square (with the coordinates `x*2, y*2`, `x*2+1, y*2`, `x*2+1, y*2+1`, `x*2, y*2+1`)

Comment: FYI this font only uses 6 pixels of width with two pixels of leading on the right hand side, so you can get away with outputting only the leftmost 6 or 7 pixels if you want (and then advancing your cursor equivalently)

Answer (score 2):

I know you can save images as a c header file in gimp. Maybe you can find a tool which does the job on the command line. So you could automate the creation. ImageMagick can at least load ttf fonts.

EDIT: Gimp does only support RGB data as output format, so it's not a solution for you.

Anyway here is an 'b' for you:

```
/* GIMP RGB C-Source image dump (b.c) */

static const struct {
  unsigned int   width;
  unsigned int   height;
  unsigned int   bytes_per_pixel; /* 3:RGB, 4:RGBA */ 
  char          *comment;
  unsigned char  pixel_data[8 * 8 * 3 + 1];
} gimp_image = {
  8, 8, 3,
  "Created with GIMP",
  "\377\377\377\377\377\377\0\0\0\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377"
  "\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\0\0\0\377\377\377\377\377\377\377"
  "\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\0\0\0\377\377\377"
  "\0\0\0\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\0\0\0"
  "\0\0\0\377\377\377\0\0\0\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377"
  "\0\0\0\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\0\0\0\377\377\377\377\377\377"
  "\377\377\377\0\0\0\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\0\0\0\377\377\377"
  "\377\377\377\377\377\377\0\0\0\377\377\377\377\377\377\0\0\0\377\377\377"
  "\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\377\377\377"
  "\377\377\377",
};
```

Comment: Once you have it in this form, in RGB, you could do some post-processing to get B&W.

Comment: Could you share the Gimp instructions for producing that code?  That's exactly what I want to do to render fonts for a simple embedded system.

Answer (score 2):

"Pixel fonts" may be a good resource:
  http://www.alvit.de/blog/article/25-best-license-free-pixelfonts

Comment: Sorry...  server must have been down :(

Comment: Server down again.

Comment: Still down.....

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20120224202425/http://www.alvit.de/blog/article/25-best-license-free-pixelfonts

Answer (score 2):

this site has many different bitmap fonts, and ways to use them:

https://jared.geek.nz/2014/jan/custom-fonts-for-microcontrollers

(its a bit old, but its very useful)

Note: their implementation of `DrawChar()` didnt work for me, so i used this instead:

```
#define CHAR_WIDTH 5
#define CHAR_HEIGHT 8

void DrawChar(unsigned char c, int x, int y, int color) {
    if (c < ' ')
        c = 0;
    else 
        c -= ' ';
    const unsigned char* chr = font[c];
    
    // Draw pixels
    for (int j = 0; j < CHAR_WIDTH; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < CHAR_HEIGHT; i++)
            if (chr[j] & (1 << i))
                drawPoint(x + j, y + i, color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't answer your question but I would recommend just using something like http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/ to generate a simple bitmap font.  Loading a tga file is pretty simple.  I wouldn't expect a crowdsourced font to look very nice.

Comment: I don't need it to look nice, it's for a quick n' dirty image tagging :-)

Answer (score 0):

Coming from Archlinux, I always first look into both the official and user package repos. There's a bunch of bdf fonts that you can use as individual packages, there's also a [bdf2c](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bdf2c/) script you can use to convert it.